# How to automatically start vncserver in the compute instance when I start it

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I created some VM instances in google cloud plataform, each time I start any of them, I need to use ssh to access the console and type "vncserver". I would like to run the vncserver command automatically when I start the instance.

Comment: One option is  to use cron @reboot feature by adding `@reboot /path/to/vncserver` to crontab

Comment: Which vncserver are you using? I might write a document on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer is to use the Google Compute Engine [Startup Script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) technology.  This defines a script that can be executed on boot of a machine.  This includes first boot and subsequent boots.  Here is a script I use that installs X and VNC if and only if VNC is not already installed.  At the end, it then starts a VNC server.  This has been tested on Compute Engines running the default OS image.

```
#!/bin/bash
dpkg-query --status vnc4server > /dev/null 2>&1
rc=$?
if [  "$rc" -ne "0" ];
then
  echo "Installing vnc components"
  apt-get update
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install xfce4 xfce4-goodies vnc4server -y
  mkdir --parents ~/.vnc
  echo "password" | vncpasswd -f > ~/.vnc/passwd
  chmod 600 ~/.vnc/passwd
fi
HOME=~ vncserver :0 -localhost no
```

You will also have to open up the firewall port for tcp/5900.

An additional option is to start the VNC server as a system service.  See [Step 4 — Running VNC as a System Service](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-debian-9#step-4-%E2%80%94-running-vnc-as-a-system-service).